# Displaying strings from an array into a UITableView within a view-based application

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Hey I have been looking all over the internet and this site for hours and nothing has come up which can solve my problem. I am very new to iPhone programming so I am sorry if this question seems too nooby. I am attempting to add a UITableView into my main view controller (part of a view-based application), and then populate its cells with strings from an array (which I already have set up). I have tried cutting and pasting the code from a default navigation based app, yet that doesn't work because the view-based app doesn't know how to react to the code. My question is how should I go about populating the table (which I dragged into the xib) with the array I made? ANY help is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SomeSubclassOfUITableViewController.m

First, implement the delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [_myStrings count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Then assign titles/subtitles/etc.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"TableCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = _myStrings[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for such a quick response! I tried what you said but when I built it, it instantly crashed and the log said "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:". Do you have any ideas what may have caused this?

Comment: That could be a number of things...if you set a breakpoint just before `return cell` and in the debugger type `po cell`, what's the output?

Comment: I'm not positive I placed the second breakpoint in the right location but the app still crashed but said "stopped at breakpoint 2." I don't think I placed the second one right, sorry but where exactly is the po cell in the debugger?

Comment: The same place you see `NSLog` output. It's the console. `(lldb) po cell` or if you have gdb, `(gdb) po cell`

Comment: Hey very sorry for being so annoying, but I have been looking for the past ten minutes for the po cell line. Is it because I just have the log displaying at the bottom pull-up window?

Comment: Nevermind the debugging thing. Just check to see that the identifier for the cell in the xib matches the one in the code, make sure your string array is initialized _before_ these delegate methods are being called, and make sure the tableview delegate and datasource are both set to the view controller (should be automatic)

Comment: Alright I did all of that and the same problem is showing up.

Comment: Hey I just fixed all the problems and now it's working great! I just had to change the line  cell.textLabel.text = _myStrings[indexPath.row]; to cell.textLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:[myArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to mention that Apple has a great tutorial covering UITableViews and some other basics. So if you have trouble understanding the code John posted, check it out: [Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1)

(I was going to add this as a comment, but I'm not awesome enough yet)

Comment: I totally agree with this..erm, comment. Table views use delegation, reusable pools, and a data source, which are all difficult concepts for starters.

Comment: hey thanks for the link to that tutorial. I checked it out and its explaining how to use the UITableView in a navigation application. The process it shows doesn't really help me out too much. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

UITableView's make use of delegation, which can be tricky when you're first starting out coding in Objective-C and for iOS.

Paul Hagerty, a computer science professor at Stanford University, has a fantastic lecture series on programming for iOS and in Objective-C [up on iTunes U here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10).

The 9th lecture covers the basics for UITableViews.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I am for sure going to check this out

Comment: No problem. The whole lecture series is really good; just use with caution since it was created based around iOS 5, so things like MapKit and being required to @synthesize Properties have changed since then. But the core basics are still the same.